# How can I make a "pretty" table overflow with plain HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two rows of words in a div (basic text output, no tables etc yet), e.g.

```
a b c d e f g h i 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now those lists can be very long and the format breaks easily on small monitors. It looks like this:

```
a b c d e f
g h i
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But I'd like to have it like that:

```
a b c d e f
1 2 3 4 5 6

g h i
7 8 9
```

How can I achieve this? I would like to use plain HTML functionality, no Javascript dependencies.

Comment: are you using any other languages?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify HTML structure?

Comment: Just HTML5/CSS3. I want to avoid dependencies such as Javascript due to NoScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of ways you can approach this:

1) Use a table.  Put the table inside a container DIV with the `overflow-x` CSS property set to `auto`.  This will make your table scrollable left and right when the screen space is too small.

2) wrap each line of the div is a container (`div`, `span`, etc) and set its `white-space` CSS property to `nowrap`.  And on the containing DIV, again use the CSS property `overflow-x: auto` to make the container scroll when screen space is too small.

3) instead of two lines of text, make each name/value pair in its own DIV, and float the DIVs to the left.  When the content wraps, the pair will wrap to the next line:

```
<div class="floatMe">a<br>1</div>
<div class="floatMe">b<br>2</div>
<div class="floatMe">c<br>3</div>
...
<div class="floatMe">ZZZ<br>999</div>

.floatMe {
  float: left;
  /* add width, padding, margin, etc to taste */
}
```

Renders like this:

```
A B C D E F G H I J  K  L  M
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

N  O  P  Q  R  S
14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: third option is interesting, +1 for that one

Comment: I'd say the first one is the best option of the tree, simply because if it looks like a duck, it quacks like a duck and it acts like a duck, better call it a duck. I.e., tables are tables. Leave that be :) But that may be a purist generation thing ;)

Comment: @GerardvanHelden I don't disagree, and it might not be a good fit in most cases but #3 is the only one to achieve the result in question

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a large `line-height` and a negative `margin-bottom` that's equal to twice the `line-height`:

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 4em;
  margin-bottom: -8em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>a b c d e f g h i</div>
<div>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</div>
```